# Kernel Panic on Macbook Air (2020)

Tags: macbook-pro, kernel-panic

My Macbook just experienced Kernel Panic and don't know what to do since it is my first time to encountered this, should I do something to prevent and to ensure that this will never happened again on my Mac however there's a lot of info's about regarding on how to fix but I'm worried that they might be bad or not reliable to trust kindly give me an suggestions.
As a first timer to encountered this kind of system issue should I do some steps regarding this or just ignored it?

My mac version is MAC OS BIG SUR 11.2.3

Answer (score 1):

**A single kernel panic is not an issue.** It happens sometimes.
Unless it happens repeatedly, I wouldn’t worry about it.

If you want to learn more about a specific kernel panic, search [kernel-panic](/questions/tagged/kernel-panic) for keywords from your log.

---

In the future if you do get **recurring kernel panics**, Apple has an official guide on things to try.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchlp2890/mac

> - Restart your Mac in Safe Mode. …
> - Uninstall any plug-ins …
> - Disconnect all devices …
> - Use Apple Diagnostics …

Answer (score 0):

As long as the Mac restarted correctly after that (ie. it only panicked the one time) and you have backups of the system, that's probably nothing to worry about. If that starts to happen more regularly, I would recommend starting in Safe Boot mode (press and hold ⇧ key on startup) and try removing login items and making sure you have enough disk space as first steps.